# How to get rid of weird perspective overlay in C4D

Tags: perspective, overlay

How can I get rid of this odd overlay? It's currently highlighted in blue ... I've tried clicking on all sorts of buttons but could not shake it off.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, Cameron. This stackexchange is more useful for you: https://blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LeoNas I agree that 3d is quite rarely discussed here but the question is about C4D and Blender stack exchange would've been as useful as this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are safe regions of your camera: Blender has the same tinted border. If you don't want it when looking through the camera, you can go to `Options > Configure > View > Tinted Border` and disable it.

Comment: Thank you Sergey

Comment: The setting in C4D is placed under `View Settings (shift+v) > View > Safe Frames` (or `Tinted Border` if you still want the frames without the tint. There you can also change the opacity and color of the overlay.